# Using a BaseActivity for OnResume Action Bar Styling

Tags: java, android

I am trying to modify a project which contains code to style the action bar. The way the styling happens is that in each FragmentActivity the following code exists:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    actionbarcolor = PreferenceData.getIntValues(AddJournalEntry.this,
            "actionbarcolor");
    if (actionbarcolor == 1) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    } else if (actionbarcolor == 2) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

I want to create a new base fragment activity class that has this code in it so that for every screen I don't have to copy/paste/update this code. i would simply extend it for the other screens. I've created a new class like so:

```
package com.fasttracksites.skyrimjournal;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.fasttracksites.adapters.PreferenceData;

public class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        actionbarcolor = PreferenceData.getIntValues(AddJournalEntry.this,
                "actionbarcolor");
        if (actionbarcolor == 1) {
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        } else if (actionbarcolor == 2) {
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        }
    }

}
```

The only issue that I see is that I need to be able to pass the context of the current screen, is it possible to do this or should I do something different?

Comment: Why don't you just extract the style of the action bar out into a resource XML?  Here is an example: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html.  This will keep your code a little cleaner since all of the styling will be in a XML file instead of your java files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have the context of the current screen, you can just use 'this'. If you have code in a parent class the reference to itself is the same in the parent and child. You can update your code like so:

```
public class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
            //Removed the AddJournalEntry before this
        actionbarcolor = PreferenceData.getIntValues(this,
                "actionbarcolor");
        if (actionbarcolor == 1) {
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        } else if (actionbarcolor == 2) {
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        }
    }

}
```

You can also style using themes in xml. If you want to get a style going fast I would highly recommend using [Android Asset Studio Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/). This is a great tool to product the required style and resource files for the action bar. Make sure to look through the files it generates to familiarize yourself with how to style the action bar using xml.